# Google Sheets - post DATE and USERNAME who edited it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works on Google Sheets as to:

- Help users update today's date in a column, and effectively add a signature.
- In a specific column, users type in any random jibberish (easy to do), and the sheet will then change this to today's date, and add their logged-in email address as a signature.

Ps the sheet does know who's currently logged in - I've set the sheet so users do have to be logged in and given access to the sheet

This is my code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d82Jq.jpg):

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
var timezone = "UTC";
var timestamp_format = "d/MM/yy"; // Timestamp Format.
var updateColName = "[code]";
var timeStampColName = "[code]";
var nameColname = "[codename]";
var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Rank Sheet'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
var nameCol = headers [0].indexOf(nameColname); nameColname = nameColname+1;
var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;

  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
cell.setValue(date + " " +userName)
var cell = sheet.getRange(index, nameColname + 1);
var nameCol = cell.setValue = (userName)
  }
}
```

To do this you need to 'title' the columns [code], and [codename] (changeable).
Thank you very much to Cooper for advice given!!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] as well more details like if you and the spreadsheet editors are using common Google accounts (i.e. user@gmail.com) or G Suite accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`cell.setValue(date + '\n' + userName)`

Comment: Thanks very much for your response!  It just completes the date (and no name is inserted etc)

This is the code I've got so far: https://imgur.com/2X3QveD

Comment: try setting the format to text wrap.  I'm inserting a linefeed so it's probably getting clipped or possible your code for getting userName is at fault

Comment: ` Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` doesn't alway return the users email.  Just because Google knows who they are does not necessarily imply that you get to know.

Comment: Fixed, the problem was the information grabbing line, successfully changed to "Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();"
thank you very much Cooper!!!